# How to correctly assign an item from a list to an object's property in Python

Tags: python, oop, list-comprehension

Suppose I want to deal out 52 numbered cards to a set of players randomly. This is the code I've written:

```
def deal(players):
    deck = [x for x in range(1,53)]
    random.shuffle(deck)
    internalObject = { 'cards': [], 'score': 0}
    starting = dict.fromkeys(players, internalObject)
    deckHasCards = True
    while (deckHasCards):
        for player in players:
            if deck == []:
                deckHasCards = False
                break
            card = deck.pop()
            starting[player]['cards'].append(card)
            card = 0


    return starting
```

The issue is that when this is run, all players end up with the same hand.

```
def main():
    hands = deal(['Jack', 'Jill'])
    print(hands)
```

Output:

```
{
'Jack': {'cards': [35, 31, 20, 15, 18, 26, 51, 19, 37, 21, 10, 44, 4, 9, 14, 52, 49, 29, 43, 5, 41, 47, 40, 7, 3, 25, 11, 22, 23, 48, 2, 32, 13, 30, 6, 16, 38, 34, 45, 36, 39, 28, 50, 24, 46, 42, 27, 1, 33, 17, 8, 12], 'score': 0}, 
'Jill': {'cards': [35, 31, 20, 15, 18, 26, 51, 19, 37, 21, 10, 44, 4, 9, 14, 52, 49, 29, 43, 5, 41, 47, 40, 7, 3, 25, 11, 22, 23, 48, 2, 32, 13, 30, 6, 16, 38, 34, 39, 28, 50, 24, 46, 42, 27, 1, 33, 17, 8, 12], 'score': 0}
}
```

What is the issue with the code here? Why is Python assigning a card to all players instead of to the player that is selected in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `dict.fromkeys(players, internalObject)` the `internalObject` dict is assigned by *reference* so both players have the same `card/score` set. To avoid that assign a new default dict to each user in a dict comprehension.
Another optimization tip is to eliminate variables `deckHasCards` and `card` as redundant (within `while` loop). 
Use the following approach:

```
def deal(players):
    deck = [x for x in range(1,53)]
    random.shuffle(deck)
    player_set = {p: {'cards': [], 'score': 0} for p in players}
    while deck:
        for player in players:
            player_set[player]['cards'].append(deck.pop())

    return player_set


def main():
    hands = deal(['Jack', 'Jill'])
    print(hands)
```

---

```
{'Jack': {'cards': [4, 41, 14, 52, 1, 10, 50, 24, 36, 20, 16, 31, 12, 46, 51, 25, 35, 17, 32, 2, 33, 45, 48, 15, 19, 43], 'score': 0}, 'Jill': {'cards': [5, 30, 49, 44, 38, 9, 28, 22, 27, 42, 39, 13, 7, 37, 8, 34, 47, 23, 29, 11, 26, 18, 40, 21, 6, 3], 'score': 0}}
```